# How to sort numbers in ag grid using comparator

Tags: javascript, sorting, ag-grid, columnsorting

I have been trying hours to solve the issue with sorting for the numeric values.
It is sorting ascending correctly  and descending correctly.
If it has null it is not sorting correctly.
Like if have 1,2,3,null 
for ascending it comes like 1,2,3,null.Here i need null at first position. 
For Descending it comes like 3,2,1,null which is correct.

> Expecting for ascending null, 1,2,3,4.
>   Actual it is 1,2,3,4,null

```
function nullsLastonSortNumber(val1, val2, node1, node2, isInverted) {

                            var isNullFirst = document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageId.oneValue}').innerHTML;


                            var currentSort= gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
                            if(isNullFirst=='false'){

                                if(currentSort[0].sort === 'asc'){

                                   if (val1 === null && val2 === null) {
                                    return 0;
                                     }
                                   if(val1 === null) {
                                    return -1;
                                    }

                                   if (val2 === null) {
                                    return 1;
                                     }
                                }
                                else if(currentSort[0].sort === 'desc'){
                                    if (val1 === null && val2 === null) 
                                    {
                                   return 0;
                                     }
                                    if (val1 === null) {
                                  return -1;
                                   }
                                  if (val2 === null) {
                                   return 1;
                                   }

                                }


                                return val1 - val2;

                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need ascending sorting with nulls first you could do something like:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,null];
arr.sort((a, b) => a-b);
```

this leads to `[null, 1, 2, 3]`

and for descending:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => b-a);
```

which leads to  `[3, 2, 1, null]`

accordingy you could rewrite your method to :

```
function nullsLastonSortNumber(val1, val2, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) {
     val1 = val1 || -Number.MAX_VALUE;
     val2 = val2 || -Number.MAX_VALUE;

     var currentSort = gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
     if(currentSort[0].sort === 'desc'){                
           return val2 - val1 
     }
     return val1 - val2;
}
```

[ag-grid custom comparator](https://plnkr.co/edit/OEtsUvZshqU8T0ot)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here it wont help. I too thought of storing it into an array and sort. Here array is getting empty. How can i add this value to the array.

Comment: could you add the code which is calling the function `nullsLastonSortNumber`? it would also be advisable to remove the method parameters `node1, node2, isInverted` which are not used and to add two parameters `isNullsFirst` and `currentSort`

Comment: i am using a comparator in aggrid column definiotion. Which is a calling this sort method. This val1,val2 are doing fine.

Comment: yes tried that too. sort works, What can I do when the value is undefined or null. Here where I am stuck. Sorting works well but when it comes to ascending null is not coming first. What can I do in that scenario??

Comment: i edited the answer to that if a null value is provided it is set the `-Number.MAX_VALUE` that should transfer all `null` values to a really small number (ie. huge negative number)

Comment: Here sorting is happening. But null is not coming first.

Comment: hi i forked a simple plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/OEtsUvZshqU8T0ot which shows how to implement a custom comparator (ageComparator) in main.js. nulls are first when ascending (inverse = false) and last when descending (inverse = true).